# How to exclude a certain name out of my table

Tags: php

I am running a gameserver and for my gameserver I made a table that shows up your items.
The table cleared it up, but the problem is that there is a item called "GMP" is spamming the list because people got it verry much.

What I want to do is excluding the item "GMP" out of that whole table but I couldn't get it out of the table.

http://puu.sh/nefH . This is how it looks like.
Here is the part of the source code to let it show this.

```
print <<<END
<br>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Item</th>
<th>+</th>
<th>Damage -</th>
<th>Extra hp</th>
<th>Position</th>
</tr>
END;


$sql6 = "SELECT t.name, i.position, p.position, i.type, i.magic3, i.reduce_dmg, i.add_life FROM cq_item i, position p, cq_itemtype t WHERE t.id = i.type AND p.id = i.position AND player_id = $id2  ORDER BY name ASC";
$execute6 = mysql_query($sql6);
while ($exibir6 = mysql_fetch_array($execute6)){;

print "<tr>";

print "<td>".$exibir6 ['name']."</td>";
print "<td>".$exibir6 ['magic3']."</td>";
print "<td>".$exibir6 ['reduce_dmg']."</td>";
print "<td>".$exibir6 ['add_life']."</td>";
print "<td>".$exibir6 ['position']."</td>";

print "</tr>";


}
print <<<END2
</table>
END2;
```

If there is something else needed just tell me and I will add it to here.

Sorry for my English it isn't my native language.

Comment: I am wondering why is that data still there if it shouldn't be shown. is there any reason why you are not deleting them ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't select items with that name (use `WHERE` for that):

```
   $sql6 = "
     SELECT t.name, i.position, p.position, i.type, i.magic3, i.reduce_dmg, i.add_life
     FROM cq_item i, position p, cq_itemtype t
     WHERE t.id = i.type AND p.id = i.position AND player_id = $id2 AND t.name != 'GMP'
     ORDER BY name ASC";
```

nb. I hope you escape/cast your query variables properly

Comment: Thanks for your really fast answer. This worked for me. For the rest everything is just working normal and fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql6 = "SELECT t.name, i.position, p.position, i.type, i.magic3, i.reduce_dmg, i.add_life FROM cq_item i, position p, cq_itemtype t WHERE t.id = i.type AND p.id = i.position AND player_id = $id2  AND t.name != 'GMP' ORDER BY name ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do an if statement in your loop.

```
<?php 
while ($exibir6 = mysql_fetch_array($execute6)){
  if($exibir6['name'] != 'GMP') {
    // Add to table
  }
}
?>
```